# Convert code to syntax highlighted html

Tags: python, html, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a python module that will let me generate "syntax highlighted" HTML code out of a code written in any of the popular languages.

Something similar to what stackoverflow does with the code tag.

Comment: Just use a JavaScript library like this one: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: Keep looking... SO is not your personal search assistant

Comment: I am not sure about python but why don't you check `Alex Gorbatchev Syntax Highlighter` which is mostly used by bloggers who want to show up code. Do check up their repo for getting an idea https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter

Comment: @Tom I need something that generates html.

Comment: @Kolink I tried goggling it, but all I find is tools like this one: http://code.google.com/p/pyh/
The search keywords are problematic here.

Comment: @Artium you mean, the program should show HTML data on a page with syntax designed by CSS ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want [pygments](http://pygments.org/).

It highlights most popular languages and outputs to HTML, RDF, LaTeX, and many more.