# How can I show syntax-highlighted Python code in a HTML-page?

Tags: python, html, css

Is it somehow possible to show syntax-highlighted python code in a webpage?

I found this:

```
<pre class="brush: python">
    # python code here
</pre>
```

However, it shows all the code in black. I want `import` to be orange, strings to be green.

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367047/407651

Comment: You can also embed a github [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to only display code, python in this case, consider using Github [gist](https://gist.github.com).

You can then embed it using the 'embed' option on the top right corner. It will give you a script tag that you can copy and add to your webpage like so:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/username/a39a422ebdff6e732753b90573100b16.js"></script>
```

Comment: @aadev151 Glad I could be of help. Please upvote/accept the answer, helps with your rep too :)

Comment: is this still working? I get 404 when I try to see the js source script

Comment: Replace the value for src with the gist URL you wish to display

Comment: Awesome! It works now but does not show up with python color highlights and colors (the script is all black and flat).. Is there any way I can get that to work?

Comment: I learned when I update .txt to .py, the color code is there but it shows up in a vertical format.

a
 
=
 
2
print
(
a
*
2
) --> url of my page using gist: https://saeedmirshekari.com/blog/test/

Answer (score 5):

I use [prism.js](https://prismjs.com/)

It looks Like this, it has many features

[image]